# Kubernetes and GPU node cluster implementation practices

Tags: tensorflow, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to understand the K8s gpu practices better, and implementing a small K8s GPU cluster which is suppose to work like below.

This going to be little long explanation, but I hope it will help to have many questions at once place to understand GPU practices better in Kubernetes.

### Application Requirement

- I want to create a K8s autoscale cluster.
- Pods are running the models say a tensorflow based deep learning program.
- Pods are waiting for a message in pub sub queue to appear and it can proceed
  its execution once it recieves a message.
- Now a message is queued in a PUB/SUB queue.
- As message is available, pods reads it and execute deep learning program.

### Cluster requirement

If no message is present in queue and none of the GPU based pods are executing program( i mean not using gpu), then gpu node pool should scale down to 0.

### Design 1

Create a gpu node pool. Each node contains N GPU, where N >= 1.
Assign model trainer pod to each gpu. That is 1:1 mapping of pods and GPU.
When I tried assigning 2 pods to 2 GPU machine where each pod is suppose to run a mnist program.

What I noticed is

1 pod got allocated and executes the program and later it went into crash loop. May be I am doing some mistake as my docker image is suppose to run program once only as I was just doing feasibility test of running 2 pods simultaneously on 2 gpu of same node.Below is the error

```
 Message   Reason  First Seen  Last Seen   Count
Back-off restarting failed container    BackOff Jun 21, 2018, 3:18:15 PM    Jun 21, 2018, 4:16:42 PM    143
pulling image "nkumar15/mnist"  Pulling Jun 21, 2018, 3:11:33 PM    Jun 21, 2018, 3:24:52 PM    5
Successfully pulled image "nkumar15/mnist"  Pulled  Jun 21, 2018, 3:12:46 PM    Jun 21, 2018, 3:24:52 PM    5
Created container   Created Jun 21, 2018, 3:12:46 PM    Jun 21, 2018, 3:24:52 PM    5
Started container   Started Jun 21, 2018, 3:12:46 PM    Jun 21, 2018, 3:24:52 PM    5
```

The other pod didn't get assigned at all to GPU. Below is the message from pod events

**0/3 nodes are available: 3 Insufficient nvidia.com/gpu.**

### Design 2

Have multiple GPU machines in gpu node pool with each node having only 1 GPU.
K8s, will assign each pod to each available GPU in node and hopefully there won't be any issue. I am yet to try this.

### Questions

1. Is there any suggested practice to design above type of system in kubernetes as of version 1.10?
2. Is Design 1 approach not feasible as of 1.10 release? For eg, I have 2 GPU node with 24 GB GPU memory, is it possible such that K8s assign 
   1 pod to each GPU and each pods execute its own workload with 12GB memory limit each?
3. How do I scale down gpu node pool to 0 size through autoscaler?
4. In Design 2, say what if I run out of GPU memory? as curently in GCP 1 GPU node doesn't have more than 16 GB memory.

Again apologies for such a long question, but I hope it will help other also.

### Updates

**For question 2**
I created a new cluster to reproduce same issue which I faced multiple times before, I am not sure what changed this time but 2nd pod is successfully allocated a GPU. I think with this result I can confirm that 1gpu-1pod mapping is allowed in a multi gpu single node
However restricting memory per gpu process is not feasible as of 1.10.

Comment: I don't see the relationship between Pub/Sub and your designs. If you can provide more details (pod specs and error messages), I can probably help with it.

Comment: I used pub/sub queue just as an example. It can be any other event on which POD is listening to.
You can see K8s deployment file here https://gist.github.com/nkumar15/03f695add43dc3be286c1d71054ebabd

For error, For 2nd pod, I didn't see any message in logs except event which is shared above
For 1st pod, I have updated error above

Comment: Realised couldn't edit comment after certain time. Just to make clear above gist shows replicaset as 1, but I tested it with 2.

Comment: Container failing to start and insufficient nvidia.com/gpu should be separate problems.

What does `kubectl logs <pod-name>` print?

What's the status of the 3 nodes? How many nvidia.com/gpu are advertised on each nodes `kubectl describe node <node-name>`?

Comment: I created a new cluster to reproduce same issue which I faced multiple times before, I am not sure what changed this time but 2nd pod is successfully allocate a GPU. I think with this result I should understand that 1gpu-1pod mapping is allowed in a multi gpu single node. For crashloop yes, I understand now that my pod docker image is configure to run only once, thats why K8s restarting the pod. If I change my pod docker image to run like web server crashloop should be eliminated. However as requested you can see my cluster details and pod logs in below comment.

Comment: all-nodes.txt
https://gist.github.com/nkumar15/3f20c944a502362959f8352556ffabfc
gpu-node.txt
https://gist.github.com/nkumar15/18fa9adf67136c227d65577372d578ba
pod1-logs.txt
https://gist.github.com/nkumar15/3bd43932ce0c7ffd734330c44f9e47b2
pod2-logs.txt
https://gist.github.com/nkumar15/857312e9b475427aef7b0133e5790981

Comment: I am not sure now how 1:1 pod-gpu mapping succeeded this time, but I will update if i faced same issue again. But still the another question is is it a good idea to go with design 1 or design 2 approach. and how we can autoscale a gpu nodepool to zero size?

Answer (score 1):

Both designs are supported in 1.10. I view design 2 as a special case of 1. You don't necessarily need to have 1 GPU per node. In case your pod needs more GPUs and memory, you have to have multiple GPUs per node, as you mentioned in question (4). I'd go with 1 unless there's a reason not to.

I think the best practice would be create a new cluster with no GPUs (a cluster has a default node pool), and then create a GPU node pool and attach it to the cluster. Your non-GPU workload can run in the default pool, and the GPU workload can run in the GPU pool. To support scaling-down to 0 GPUs, you need to set `--num-nodes` and `--min-nodes` to be 0 when creating the GPU node pool.

Docs:

*Create a cluster with no GPUs: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-cluster#creating_a_cluster*

*Create a GPU node pool for an existing cluster: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/gpus#gpu_pool*

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Now I have better clarity on design approach. The only reason I see not to use design 1 is when each POD can consume more than its share of memory. Is there any way to set memory limit per gpu pod? By the way with autoscaling, I think the issue is, autoscale cannot scale down gpu nodepool to 0 node, since it cannot migrate pod  to non-gpu nodes even when pods are not executing (using gpu). Please correct my understanding.

Comment: is memory limit request for cpu applicable for gpu nodes also?

Comment: for above question, I set memory limit in pod for gpu, but it couldn't be deployed. It failed with error 0/3 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient nvidia.com/gpu, 3 Insufficient memory. you can see pod error here https://gist.github.com/nkumar15/fa3c7a3ed6e74248f750cecde0157a78. Does it mean memory cannot be set in limit for gpu pods?

Comment: Re autoscaling

From the doc I linked:

`This causes only Pods requesting GPUs to be scheduled on GPU nodes, which enables more efficient autoscaling: your GPU nodes can quickly scale down if there are not enough Pods requesting GPUs.`



`memory` is not for GPU memory.

Comment: Agree, but my confusion is, lets say  a pod (gpu)  is scheduled to a gpu. But it is not doing anything coz there is no request/event present, which causes pod to execute gpu program. Now in this case even though deep learning program is not executing but pod is still scheduled to a gpu. This doesn't allow autoscale to reduce gpu node pool count to 0, as K8s cannot assign this pod to non gpu machine. Over all I think what exactly needed is to create gpu pods on demand and assign it to available gpu, otherwise spawn a new gpu instance and assign the new pod to it. Is this scheme possible?

Comment: You can create GPU pods on demand from the pod that listens to messages from pub/sub. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#accessing-the-cluster-api